# 02287. 00000 - "sequence number not allowed here"

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a sequence with maxvalue as 10. I am trying to insert values in multiple tables using single insert statement but getting following error.
02287. 00000 -  "sequence number not allowed here"

```
insert all into test_t1 values (col1,col2)
into test_t2 values (col1,col2)
select test_seq.nextval col1, test_seq.currval col2 
from dual;
```

Comment: I think you can't use CURRVAL or NEXTVAL Within a single SQL statement

Comment: But if I run the select statement alone it   fetches correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to CURRVAL & NEXTVAL in a single SQL statement, but not in the source for an INSERT ALL statement.

Refer:

https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6915127515933

http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287